# select data from two or mre tables using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to implement a search function. 
I have two tables named `tbl_table` and `tbl_roomavailability`. I need to search for a hotel that is available for a particular date interval i.e., need to search if the room is available and also need to display the hotels from the hotel table. See my code:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT( H.`int_hotel_id`), H.str_hotelName, H.str_logo_thumb, H.str_aboutHotel
FROM
    tbl_hotel H
INNER JOIN
    tbl_roomavailability RA
        ON H.int_hotel_id = RA.int_hotel_id
WHERE
    bit_complete = 1 AND
    H.int_zone_id = 10 AND
    H.int_city_id = 1 AND
    H.int_hotelcatId = 3 AND
    RA.str_date IN (1334966400,1335052800,1335139200,1335225600,1335312000,1335398400,1335484800,1335571200,1335657600,1335744000)
ORDER BY
    H.int_hotel_id DESC;
```

With this query i need to display the entire hotel id which matches the zone, city sate from `tbl_hotel`. Currently my results are the hotels which are present in the room availability table.

I need to display both. i.e. need to check if the hotel is present in the room availability and also the hotels which are satisfied the other condition in the hotel table.

Suppose I have 3 hotels

Hotel 1 - state=7, zone=3 which is present in the room availability table
Hotel 2 State 7 zone=3 which is **not present** in the room availability
Hotel 3 state 8 zones 4 which is present in the room availability
Hotel 4 state 7 zone 3 which is **present** in the room availability but **not available** for several month

When I search for a hotel with state 7 and zone 3, then I need to display hotel1 and hotel2 (I don't want to display the hotel 4 because it's not available for a several month).

I think it's clear
Does anyone know?
Please reply

Comment: (Please check/clean your keyboard, you're dropping letters all over the place.)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please provide some sample data, the results you are currently getting and the results you want to get.

Comment: select DISTINCT( h.`int_hotel_id`) AS hotel_id Is that what you meant?